# Remove styles from one div if other div's styles are active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I'm looking for a help with a small things to do on my CMS website.

I would like to know, if it's possible, how to to remove or hide styles from one div one a website while another div is active and only when this 2nd div is inside the first one.

I'm using easytabs jQuery plugin and easytabs html code is inserted in tinymce WYSIWYG HTML source editor, while `<div class="block"></div>` is generated from CMS, because it's a wrapper of content module.

Let me show you my code so maybe you can understand more what I want to do:

```
<div class="block">
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
  <ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-html">HTML Markup</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-js">Required JS</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-css">Example CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs1-html">
    <h2>HTML Markup for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs1-js">
    <h2>JS for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs1-css">
    <h2>CSS Styles for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Okay, so CMS is adding `<div class="block"></div>` with a styles

(thats are the styles):

```
#main .block {
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 24px 28px 24px 26px;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And here comes the problem. I would like to remove or hide styles from this `<div class="block"></div>` element only while I have `<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container"></div>` inside this div `<div class="block"></div>`.

And I need to keep all the styles for `<div class="block"></div>` when I have other divs inside it.

Is it doable with some jQuery or JS ? Or it's not possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to remove the css styles for .block when <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container" is available ? Is this the only requirement ?

Comment: You can't select a parent element based on it's child elements using just CSS. You need to use jQuery's `.hasClass()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `has()` function within jQuery. You're going to have to reset or change each of the CSS values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').has('#tab-container.tab-container').css('border', '0');
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="some_tag">
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

You can do an array of CSS values as well if there is more than one that needs to be changed like so:

```
.css({ "border": "0", "background": "blue"})
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped a lot :) I have one more question related to this. What if I dont know the name of div's class or id that's inside a div I want to remove styles from ?

Comment: You could just find out if they're divs or spans and at what level etc. If you don't know the selectors then how else are you meant to select them to remove css? :P

Comment: Well actually I think I know the structure

Comment: If you know the structure then doing the finds etc should be easy to do

Comment: You'll never learn if you don't try it yourself. Try and amend my code above to get it to work with your structure and if you have problems/errors then chat to me on the chat system :)

Comment: Ok I think this is not necessary anymore to do with random div id or class, cause editor do not create a div when you write anything in it but only paragraphs. So it's okay they way it is and thank you again for your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Insteed of resetting or overwritte all block classes maybe it would be much easier to add:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('.block').has('div.tab-container').removeClass('block');
        });
```

This way you will remove the block class so no styles.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/q17bvL3z/)**

Comment: Thank you ! This and Stewartside's answers helped me a lot now I can use both of this :)